# .NET programmability support keeps getting disabled (randomly?)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I am not sure if this is the correct location to be asking this question but I am absolutely baffled, and could really use some help.

I have several users at work that utilize one of our in-house software packages that generates emails and exports to excel (it utilizes the office.dll's). One of these many users randomly (we have been unable to detect a pattern) throws exceptions because his Microsoft Office 2013 install loses it's '.NET Programmability support'.

When this happens, we can go to Control Panel > Programs > Office 2013 > Change, and toggle '.NET Programmability Support' to 'Off' for all of the office products, and then complete the Modification. Then repeat this process but toggle it back to 'On'. It will remedy the issue for 1-3 days and then he loses it again.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this may be happening, and how we might be able to fix this?

Office 2013
Latest version of Windows 10 (Same as other users that do not have the issue)

Comment: This sounds like a group policy for Office is being enforced.  Does the machine appear on the domain?  Have you attempted to forcefully enforce the group polciies on the machine?  have you checked if the group policy is set properly?

Comment: Was the feature set to "not available" during deploying Office 2013? Please make sure .NET framework 3.5 is installed. You can refer to [Install the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10) to enable it. Please follow @ Ramhound 's suggestion to check group policy.

Comment: We don't enforce anything like that through group policy on our network. The machine does appear on the domain. I cannot speak for the initial install because I did not perform it, however, I performed a complete uninstall/reinstall of office and it was set to on at that point. When the problem occurs, the feature is set to "Run from my computer". (I suspect that this is a false positive)